# Problems with spring and log4j2

Tags: log4j2

I encountered the following problem when I upgraded log4j from 1.2.17 to 2.13.3. The problem was that when spring booted the bean, it told me that I did not introduce the log4j jar.
I found out because spring uses commons-logging as log output by default, so I introduced the jar slf4j and log4j-slf4j-impl, but the problem is still not solved

This is the error details:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataUploadServiceImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/E:/WorkSpace/git/dmc_idx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp2/wtpwebapps/DMC-IDX-CORE/WEB-INF/lib/dmc-idx-service-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/ai/dmc/index/service/dataupload/DataUploadServiceImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Priority
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Priority
    at com.ai.frame.logger.LoggerFactory.getUtilLog(LoggerFactory.java:93) ~[control-2.5.jar:?]
    at com.ai.frame.logger.LoggerFactory.getUtilLog(LoggerFactory.java:134) ~[control-2.5.jar:?]
    at com.ai.frame.bean.Entity.<clinit>(Entity.java:20) ~[control-2.5.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.<clinit>(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:739) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:123) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:473) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:355) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization
```

This is the pom.xml details:

```
<dependency>   
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>  
    <version>2.13.3</version>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</ groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the log4j-1.2-api jar. However, com.ui.frame.logger.LoggerFactory.getUtilLog is probably not going to behave correctly since it is still coded to use Log4j 1 so while adding the jar may fix this problem you still might see more after that.

Comment: But the company requires that log4j1.x must be removed, so I cannot introduce 1.2

Comment: Sorry, I really want to find the reason. I quoted another private jar of the company. This jar contains log4j1.x.

Comment: log4j-1.2-api.jar replaces your log4j-1.x.jar file and meets the requirements of your company. It allows you to continue to use the Log4j 1.x api but use Log4j 2 as the implementation. You will want to transition those over time to the Log4j 2 API over time but using it makes it so you don't have to do it in one big bang.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have always put the problem in the jar conflict before, thank you for pointing me